# Synchronous HTTP Client with .NET sockets

Tags: c#, http, sockets

Does anyone know of any open source C# projects or some sample code that implement a synchronous HTTP client using sockets?

I'm working on a project where I need a HTTP client using sockets.  It can't use WebRequest or WebClient, nor can it use Asynchronous sockets. Don't ask.  Also it would ideally be on .NET 2.0, yeah very cutting edge here.

I figured the web would have tons of samples for this but suprisingly I couldn't find any. Probably because everyone is fortunate enough to use the built in APIs.

If I don't find something I'll have to write it myself, which I don't really want to have to reinvent that wheel.

Comment: Why can't you use WebRequest or WebClient? :-P

Comment: These kind of completely artificial restrictions are only typical in homework assignments.  Be sure to tag your question as such or you're not likely to get much help.

Comment: This is NOT homewok Hans, but a legitemate request for a production system.  If I could use one of the existing APIs I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: Can you specify why you can't use the existing API's?  That would help narrow down the list of alternatives.  For instance, you could use the source for WebClient from Mono (or the BCL or whatever).

I'd especially love to know about production systems that would rather make their own API like this instead of using the one in the framework that's had tons more testing and fixes already applied. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample for FTP using raw sockets.

http://www.csharphelp.com/2005/11/ftp-client-library-in-c/

HTTP protoocol is simpler than ftp though https more complex than the both put together.

I see not using WebRequest or WebClientif you were writting a web-crawler.